# What is Nick Bostrom's 'Fable of the Dragon-Tyrant' an analogy of?

Tags: short-stories, symbolism, nick-bostrom

Available, freely, online, is Nick Bostrom's [*The Fable of the Dragon-Tyrant* (2005)](https://nickbostrom.com/fable/dragon.html), an essay or short story about a fictional dragon's tyranny and effect on/cost to society.

CGP Grey adapted it into a narrated animation

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cZYNADOHhVY

What are the themes in the story a metaphor for? I understand that [dragons are sometimes used metaphorically to refer to cancer](https://www.popmatters.com/representing-a-disease-in-that-dragon-cancer-2495456912.html), has that got to do with it?

Comment: Is that [*the* Nick Bostrom](https://www.simulation-argument.com/classic.html)?

Comment: @Randal'Thor Right. I feel like he wouldn't waste time mincing words with fables unless it was to elicit a strong moral that could be mapped onto something modern and non-fictional (my thoughts were disease (including cancer and "old age"), as these seem like topics of interest to him, from what little I have gathered)

Comment: It seems the end section on "moral" fairly clearly indicates he's talking about old age.

Answer (score 3):

The dragon is a metaphor for Death, particularly by old age and by disease.

This ties directly into Grey's previous recent video, ["Why Die?"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C25qzDhGLx8), where he makes the same argument but without the metaphor.

By providing a manifestation, a dragon "responsible" for death, and people accepting its inevitability, Bostrom argues that the world has accepted the *fact* of Death as inevitable, even when that might no longer be the case.

Bostrom himself writes, [in the original text](https://nickbostrom.com/fable/dragon.html):

> Stories about aging have traditionally focused on the need for graceful accommodation. The recommended solution to diminishing vigor and impending death was resignation coupled with an effort to achieve closure in practical affairs and personal relationships. Given that nothing could be done to prevent or retard aging, this focus made sense.
>
> Today we face a different situation. While we still lack effective and acceptable means for slowing the aging process, we can identify research directions that might lead to the development of such means in the foreseeable future.
>
> Many distinguished technologists and scientists tell us that it will become possible to retard, and eventually to halt and reverse, human senescence. (...) Our situation with regard to human senescence is closely analogous and ethically isomorphic to the situation of the people in the fable with regard to the dragon. Therefore, we have compelling moral reasons to get rid of human senescence.
>
> The argument is not in favor or life-span extension per se. Adding extra years of sickness and debility at the end of life would be pointless. The argument is in favor of extending, as far as possible, the human health-span.

Comment: Hurray, Standback is back in the game! :-)

Comment: LOL. A rare combination of my email notifications getting triggered -- one for CGP Grey, one for a short-story question on Lit.SE...